# Get system filepath using Capacitor Filesystem API

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-plugin

currently I'm working through the tutorial of building my first app with using the ionicframework with angular and I would like to know where the photos are actually saved on my filesystem? I tried to find out using `Filesystem.getURI()` but `/DATA/1614347102940.jpeg` doesn't really help me.

Does anyone know what the absolue filepath on my system is or how I can find out?

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the use case a bit more? Or provide link to the tutorial?

Comment: There is no specific use case. I just want to have the control over the data which is stored on my local machine. Since capacitor seems to be using the IndexedDB feature of the browser this seems to be impossible. Or at least my knowledge of the IndexedDB feature approximates zero. Here the link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/3-saving-photos

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the `Filesystem` [plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/apis/filesystem#understanding-directories-and-files). The plugin abstracts each operation to a specific special [directory](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/apis/filesystem#directory) on the device. Used like so:

```js
import { Filesystem, Directory } from '@capacitor/core';

Directory.Documents
Directory.Data
Directory.Cache
Directory.External
Directory.ExternalStorage
```

[source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/blob/1a831abfb4237c72bd4c8c62c8b6681e3f17f55e/filesystem/src/definitions.ts#L7)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out that ionic or capacitor uses the IndexedDB of the browser which makes it impossible, I guess, to find the file on the filesystem of my local machine.